# ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR tried everything

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, network-protocols, spdy

Things I've tried:

Cleared temp files, cookies, and caches
Flushing SPDY Sockets using chrome://net-internals/#sockets
Updated browser
Flushing DNS and Renewing IP

I use sitelock to scan for malware but I don't see an HTTPS scanner to disable there (as has been recommended). I use hostgator cPanel for FTP and don't see any antivirus on there besides sitelock.

This error only happens on chrome but using chrome is not an option and severely slows traffic for desktop and android users, as well as those of us on the admin side.

I am getting the error from a different file almost every time. Sometimes AMP Poppins-light font files, sometimes plugin files, sometimes even wp-admin and wp-include files which I have fully reinstalled. I am suspicious of one thing which is that this started persisting once I implemented AMP-auto-ads from adsense. However removing those ads does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally turned out to be a server error: old apache connections stacking up. This has been prevented by lowering the  Keep-Alive functionality from 5 minutes to 2.